# How to mount a disk on root for Kodi

Tags: kodi

I finally updated my media machine to Linux Mint 20.1. In the process switched from XMBC to Kodi.

I changed the disks that data is on. But I can't find a way to get Kodi to see it. Except if I let the system mount it like a removable disk.

I have tried adding links in places Kodi does see, but it doesn't seem to see links.

I have the disk mounted on /data, and it's not showing in the root file system browser.

The disk shows in the browser, but doesn't do anything.

I looked at the how to page, but I didn't see any detailed permissions or anything that sounded like extra setup.

I don't have any ideas, except to mount the smb share when I get that set up.

Any one know about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the place for answers.

https://forum.kodi.tv/forumdisplay.php?fid=52

In looking at the how to file a bug report and a couple of other topics, I got to thinking. I had installed using the Ubuntu Software tool. So I uninstalled that and installed from the xmdc team ppa. That showed me the mount point. Then I had to open permissions for OTHERS and I got the files.